# error message when running parser.add_argument("--cuda", default=False, action='store_true', help="Enable cuda computation")

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm running along a code example from Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-on book, chapter 3, 03_random_action_wrapper.py. The code can be found in Github link https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter03/03_atari_gan.py

Alternatively please see below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import argparse
import cv2

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

import torchvision.utils as vutils

import gym
import gym.spaces

import numpy as np

log = gym.logger
log.set_level(gym.logger.INFO)

LATENT_VECTOR_SIZE = 100
DISCR_FILTERS = 64
GENER_FILTERS = 64
BATCH_SIZE = 16

# dimension input image will be rescaled
IMAGE_SIZE = 64

LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
REPORT_EVERY_ITER = 100
SAVE_IMAGE_EVERY_ITER = 1000


class InputWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    """
    Preprocessing of input numpy array:
    1. resize image into predefined size
    2. move color channel axis to a first place
    """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(InputWrapper, self).__init__(*args)
        assert isinstance(self.observation_space, gym.spaces.Box)
        old_space = self.observation_space
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(
            self.observation(old_space.low),
            self.observation(old_space.high),
            dtype=np.float32)

    def observation(self, observation):
        # resize image
        new_obs = cv2.resize(
            observation, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
        # transform (210, 160, 3) -> (3, 210, 160)
        new_obs = np.moveaxis(new_obs, 2, 0)
        return new_obs.astype(np.float32)


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        # this pipe converges image into the single number
        self.conv_pipe = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=input_shape[0], out_channels=DISCR_FILTERS,
                      kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=DISCR_FILTERS, out_channels=DISCR_FILTERS*2,
                      kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(DISCR_FILTERS*2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=DISCR_FILTERS * 2, out_channels=DISCR_FILTERS * 4,
                      kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(DISCR_FILTERS * 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=DISCR_FILTERS * 4, out_channels=DISCR_FILTERS * 8,
                      kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(DISCR_FILTERS * 8),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=DISCR_FILTERS * 8, out_channels=1,
                      kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        conv_out = self.conv_pipe(x)
        return conv_out.view(-1, 1).squeeze(dim=1)


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_shape):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        # pipe deconvolves input vector into (3, 64, 64) image
        self.pipe = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=LATENT_VECTOR_SIZE, out_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 8,
                               kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(GENER_FILTERS * 8),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 8, out_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 4,
                               kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(GENER_FILTERS * 4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 4, out_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 2,
                               kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(GENER_FILTERS * 2),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=GENER_FILTERS * 2, out_channels=GENER_FILTERS,
                               kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(GENER_FILTERS),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=GENER_FILTERS, out_channels=output_shape[0],
                               kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.pipe(x)


def iterate_batches(envs, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE):
    batch = [e.reset() for e in envs]
    env_gen = iter(lambda: random.choice(envs), None)

    while True:
        e = next(env_gen)
        obs, reward, is_done, _ = e.step(e.action_space.sample())
        if np.mean(obs) > 0.01:
            batch.append(obs)
        if len(batch) == batch_size:
            # Normalising input between -1 to 1
            batch_np = np.array(batch, dtype=np.float32) * 2.0 / 255.0 - 1.0
            yield torch.tensor(batch_np)
            batch.clear()
        if is_done:
            e.reset()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--cuda", default=False, action='store_true',
        help="Enable cuda computation")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    device = torch.device("cuda" if args.cuda else "cpu")
    envs = [
        InputWrapper(gym.make(name))
        for name in ('Breakout-v0', 'AirRaid-v0', 'Pong-v0')
    ]
    input_shape = envs[0].observation_space.shape

    net_discr = Discriminator(input_shape=input_shape).to(device)
    net_gener = Generator(output_shape=input_shape).to(device)

    objective = nn.BCELoss()
    gen_optimizer = optim.Adam(
        params=net_gener.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE,
        betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    dis_optimizer = optim.Adam(
        params=net_discr.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE,
        betas=(0.5, 0.999))
    writer = SummaryWriter()

    gen_losses = []
    dis_losses = []
    iter_no = 0

    true_labels_v = torch.ones(BATCH_SIZE, device=device)
    fake_labels_v = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE, device=device)

    for batch_v in iterate_batches(envs):
        # fake samples, input is 4D: batch, filters, x, y
        gen_input_v = torch.FloatTensor(
            BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_VECTOR_SIZE, 1, 1)
        gen_input_v.normal_(0, 1)
        gen_input_v = gen_input_v.to(device)
        batch_v = batch_v.to(device)
        gen_output_v = net_gener(gen_input_v)

        # train discriminator
        dis_optimizer.zero_grad()
        dis_output_true_v = net_discr(batch_v)
        dis_output_fake_v = net_discr(gen_output_v.detach())
        dis_loss = objective(dis_output_true_v, true_labels_v) + \
                   objective(dis_output_fake_v, fake_labels_v)
        dis_loss.backward()
        dis_optimizer.step()
        dis_losses.append(dis_loss.item())

        # train generator
        gen_optimizer.zero_grad()
        dis_output_v = net_discr(gen_output_v)
        gen_loss_v = objective(dis_output_v, true_labels_v)
        gen_loss_v.backward()
        gen_optimizer.step()
        gen_losses.append(gen_loss_v.item())

        iter_no += 1
        if iter_no % REPORT_EVERY_ITER == 0:
            log.info("Iter %d: gen_loss=%.3e, dis_loss=%.3e",
                     iter_no, np.mean(gen_losses),
                     np.mean(dis_losses))
            writer.add_scalar(
                "gen_loss", np.mean(gen_losses), iter_no)
            writer.add_scalar(
                "dis_loss", np.mean(dis_losses), iter_no)
            gen_losses = []
            dis_losses = []
        if iter_no % SAVE_IMAGE_EVERY_ITER == 0:
            writer.add_image("fake", vutils.make_grid(
                gen_output_v.data[:64], normalize=True), iter_no)
            writer.add_image("real", vutils.make_grid(
                batch_v.data[:64], normalize=True), iter_no)
```

But when I run the code it gave me the below error message. Specifically this error message came out when I run. I'm using Pycharm in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and GPU is RTX 3080.

```
parser.add_argument(
        "--cuda", default=False, action='store_true',
        help="Enable cuda computation")
```

### Error message

```
usage: pydevconsole.py [-h] [--cuda]
pydevconsole.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --mode=client --port=33645
Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: What is the exact command you used to run the script?

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for the comment, but not sure if I follow your question. I ran the code in Pycharm, tried it on Colab as well and didn't work. Did I answer your question or have I misunderstood it?

Comment: My question is which script did you run? As in: how did you run the code?

Comment: I first run all of the code from the Github link I included. It returned that error message. Then I restart the Kernel and run the code line by line, and the error message came out when I run `parser.add_argument(
        "--cuda", default=False, action='store_true',
        help="Enable cuda computation")`

Comment: I understand, but my question is how do you actually "run all the code from the Github link"? Are you clicking on execute option on your IDE? Are you executing a particular command line?

Comment: My apology for not making this clear and misunderstanding the question. In the IDE (pycharm), I select all of the codes (control A) and execute selection in python console (alt shift e)